# jQuery jCarousel Lite thumbnail navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, thumbnails, jcarousellite

I'm using the script from http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/ and now I need the thumbs to work as nav buttons

I have 5 visible images and I want the image I click on to center... Any idea on how to fix that?

my idea is to get the clicked items index like this:

```
var activeItem = $('.carousel li a').index(this)-2;
```

and then set that item as start:

```
$carousel.jCarouselLite({
 start: activeItem,
 visible: 5
});
```

this sort of works but it breaks the "circular: true" feature.

Even if I set start: to anything but 0 the bug appears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the newer and better plugin https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-carousel-lite

it has a lot of bugs fixed